# Non Duplicate Number Secquence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a key safe and the entry code has been lost. The digests on the safe are 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 and 0. 
I want a list of all possible entry codes. Entry codes can not have the same number twice, and the sequence of numbers is irrelevant, ie 22, is the same as 2, 221 is the same as 12 and 2345  is the same as 2543, 2435, 3452, 4532, ect, so only 2345 would be in the answer list.

How can i generate this list in excel when can I obtain such a list?

Thanks Adam Lewis

Answer (score 1):

In Excel, I think you will need a separate column for each number of elements in the code.  To give an example, take the codes with $4$ digits.  We will find the codes in ascending order.  There are ${10 \choose 4}=210$ of them, which you can get from the COMBIN function.  The first ${9 \choose 3}=84$ of them start with $0$.  The rest don't have a zero.  So put a zero in the first position of the first $84$.  The same strategy will find the first digit of each code.  Recurse.

Answer (score 0):

To generate the list, first pick a number $a_1$ from $\{1,...,n\}$. Then you pick a number $a_2$ from $\{a_1,...,n\}$. Keep going as long as you want/can, i.e. stop at any point $a_i$ or when the last number picked was $9$. This should generate your unique list.

For example:
$n=1$ is just the digits, $n=2$ is:
$$
12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,23,24,\ldots,78,79,89.
$$

Comment: Thanks Ian, but how do I physically create or obtain this list? I am not really keen on sitting down with a pen and paper...

Comment: Hi Ian can you give me an example of just 1-3?

Answer (score 0):

This is really a programming question.

1. Generate a column of all 4 digit sequences.
2. Use mod(,10) and /10 to get each digit in a separate column.
3. In another column, use or(a=b,a=c,a=d,b=c,b=d,c=d) to test for equal digits.
4. Sort your table with this last column ascending, then by the 4 digit sequence column ascending.
5. Delete out the rows with or(a=b,a=c,a=d,b=c,b=d,c=d) = TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can have codes $1$ to $9$ and you don't count repeated numbers, you're essentially looking for all subsets of $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9\}$.

With R this can be done as `lapply(0:9, function(x) combn(9,x))`.